# Quiero abrir multiples archivos, pero cuando lo hago solo me muestra el primero

Tags: c

estoy haciendo un codigo que deba leer 2 archivos e imprimlo todo en un 3ero aparte, pero primero quiero asegurarme que todo va bien imprimiendo los datos del archivo en la consola, lo que me deberia mostrar todo, el problema es que solo me muestra el primero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE*Lec=fopen("1.txt","rb");
    FILE*Flujo=fopen("2.txt","rb");
    char mapa[10];
    char letra[10];
    int numero;
    char slot[10];
    if ((Lec && Flujo)==NULL){
        perror("Error en la apertura de los archivos\n\n");
    }else{
        while (feof(Lec)==0){
            fscanf(Lec, "%s", &mapa);
            printf("%s", mapa);
        }
        fclose(Lec);
        printf("\n");
        while (feof(Flujo)==0){
            fscanf(Flujo,"%s%d%s", &letra, &numero, &slot);
            printf("%s %d %s\n", letra, numero, slot);
        }
        fclose(Flujo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Para leer archivos utilizaria la función fgets() y la colocaria dentro del while() para evitar que se duplique la ultima linea:

```
while(fgets(mapa,10,Lec))
```

De ahi en mas todo quedaria en manejo de strings

2) Cuando envias un string a scanf no debes incluir el caracter & antes del nombre, ya que en realidad, el nombre de un string contiene la direccion del primer elemento, eso significa que las sentencias:

```
scanf("%s",mapa);
```

es equivalente a la sentencia

```
scanf("%s",&mapa[0]);
```

Saludos y suerte!

Answer (score 0):

ya intentaste utilizar `"r+"`, abre el fichero para leer y escribir. claro, el fichero debe existir, verificar tambien si ya estan creados los archivos en tu computadora,

o tambien yo cambiaria:

```
if (Lec==NULL && Flujo==NULL){//suerte
```